# What is the simplest CMS for my needs?

Tags: cms

I'm looking for a CMS that meets the following specifications:

- easy to maintain and update
- content is modified by a variety of users with different kinds of access
- templated enough to quickly make aesthetically pleasing sites

I have no experience with using a CMS but I have some knowledge in html and object oriented programming.

Comment: Most of what you are asking about is entirely subjective. Regardless, this is off topic on SO. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: This is just as off-topic on Server Fault as it was on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It would fit webmasters.stackexchange.com better.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are talking about CMS for blogs ?

One of the most popular and used is

[Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/)

Comment: Part of it will be blog-esque. Not all of it though. The two that look the most appealing so far are drupal and plone.